# Why do I get an enumeration error using xlwings to return the result of an Excel add-in function?

Tags: python, excel, typeerror, enumeration, xlwings

I have an Excel addin that has a formula I would like to use.  I have xlwings update the spreadsheet with the formula and then get the value of the formula.

I have had numerous times where I have received an enumeration error when I am using xlwings.  Is there a way to get past this error with error handling?

I have the following code:

```
for attempt in range(10):
        try:
            wb.sheets('Sheet1').range('A1').value = '=KSINV(0.05,'+str(sum1)+','+str(sum2)+')'
        except:
            w=0#nothing
        else:
            break

for attempt2 in range(10):
        try:
            dcrit=wb.sheets('Sheet1').range('A1').value
        except:
            w2=0#nothing
        else:
            break
```

This does not seem to be helping.  Do I need to increase the attempts?

Comment: Perhaps try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33151033/18571565), to load the add-in to ensure that it is active before your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the addin when suddenly the formula for the function I was using included the path to the xlam before the function.

I copied the xlam file as a different name and activated the addin with that name.  I haven't had an error since.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).